# How to change font size of NSTableHeaderCell

Tags: swift, cocoa, fonts, size, nstableview

I am trying to change the font size of my NSTableView within my code to allow the user to change it to their liking. 
I was successful by changing the font size of each NSTableCellView but failed to do so by the header cells.

I was trying to do it like this

```
let headerCell = NSTableHeaderCell()
let font = NSFont(name: "Arial", size: 22.0)
headerCell.stringValue = "firstname"
headerCell.font = font
customerTable.tableColumns[0].headerCell = headerCell
```

The stringValue of the header cell will be set accordingly but the size does not change. How can I change the font size of my headers?

Thanks

Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `NSTableHeaderCell` subclass and implement the property you want to change.

In Objective-C (I'm not good at Swift):

```
@implementation CustomTableHeaderCell

-(NSFont *)font {
    return [NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:22];
}

// you can alse custom textColor
-(NSColor *)textColor {
    return [NSColor redColor];
}

@end
```

Assign `CustomTableHeaderCell`:

```
CustomTableHeaderCell *headerCell = [[CustomTableHeaderCell alloc] init];
headerCell.stringValue = @"Header title";
self.tableView.tableColumns[0].headerCell = headerCell;
```

[image: Screenshot]

In Cocoa, there are many things you can't change its style by `cell.font = ...`, you need to create a subcalss.

Comment: The property font is already part of NSCell that is the base class of NSTableHeaderCell. So the property is there but it's not considered somehow.

Comment: @OliverKoehler I try my solution in Swift, it seems doesn't work.

Comment: no you are right. I've created a CustomTableHeaderCell that inherits from NSTableHeaderCell. However it is enough to set the property of the base class (NSView) in order to work properly. I will upload my code when I am back at work.

Answer (score 3):

So, finally I was only able to solve this with subclassing NSTableHeaderCell. It was somehow strange as Swift and Cocoa always tend to favor composition over inheritance but anyway.

Swift 3.1

```
final class CustomTableHeaderCell : NSTableHeaderCell {

    override init(textCell: String) {
        super.init(textCell: textCell)
        self.font = NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18) // Or set NSFont to your choice
        self.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        // skip super.drawWithFrame(), since that is what draws borders
        self.drawInterior(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
    }

    override func drawInterior(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        let titleRect = self.titleRect(forBounds: cellFrame)
        self.attributedStringValue.draw(in: titleRect)
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is not working properly, the font size have no effect, and when you click on the header the behaviors is weird

Answer (score 2):

Changing attributedStringValue will do the trick

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableColumns.forEach { (column) in

        column.headerCell.attributedStringValue = NSAttributedString(string: column.title, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)])

        // Optional: you can change title color also jsut by adding NSForegroundColorAttributeName
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXJyu.png

Comment: tableView.tableColumns.forEach { (column) in...    This method work for me but only the first colum header have change.   How do I speciy all the column header ?