# Customise NSTableView Header, background color, remove border

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I need to add a background color, change title font and remove the border on my NSTableView headers.

I have draw a background with red color and adjust header height size but I don't find any way to customise it more. Here is all I can achieve :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTable.tableColumns[0].headerCell = CustomHeaderCell()
    myTable.headerView?.frame.size.height = 50
}


class CustomHeaderCell: NSTableHeaderCell {
    override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
    super.draw(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
    controlView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change font size of NSTableHeaderCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510646/how-to-change-font-size-of-nstableheadercell)

Comment: that code isn't working

Comment: The accepted answer works but doesn't remove the border. The other anwer needs tweaking. Is a floating group row an option?

Comment: yes maybe, I don't know what is floating group row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would assign your a custom NSTableHeaderCell to each cell of NSTableView.
This can be done in a subclass of NSTableView (as below) or in the View controller (viewDidLoad)

```
override func awakeFromNib() {

    for column in self.tableColumns{
        column.headerCell = HeaderCell(textCell: column.headerCell.stringValue)
    }
}
```

In your custom NSTableHeaderCell you can override `func drawInterior(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView)` to customise the drawing and text.

```
    override func drawInterior(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {

    NSColor.green.set()

    let rect = NSRect(x: cellFrame.origin.x, y: cellFrame.origin.y - 3, width: cellFrame.size.width - 2, height: cellFrame.size.height + 10)
    NSBezierPath(rect: rect).fill()

    let str = NSAttributedString(string: stringValue, attributes:
        [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.red,
         NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont(name: "Skia", size: 14)])

    str.draw(in: cellFrame)

}
```

To customise further cell drawing (like borders) you can override `func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView)` as well.

```
   override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        self.drawInterior(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
    }
```

Of course you can use hardcoded attributes or the ones provided by the cell.

Comment: nice code, but if we click on a header the view is changing to a weird thing

Comment: Do you mean that the text moves down ? Table header are clickable by default and would allow to change the sort order in a proper implementation. I was only concentrating on how to customise the drawing. Dependent on your requirement you will have to deactivate this behaviour or to implement it as well.

Comment: How would you remove the border in the draw function?

Comment: There should be different drawing functions you can play around. I stopped to use it and moved on with SwiftUI. You should do the same  :-)